# button link based on URL

Tags: javascript, html

I need a JS code that will create link depending on user location
in the bottom of the page, there will be 3 different buttons
for example, if I'm located in the page "/a/001/" I will have 1 link to "/b/001/" and the second link to "/a/002"
when I'm in the "/b/003/" I will have  1: "/b/002" 2: "/b/004/" and the last one "/a/002/"

if its possible to create a JS code to check the URL element and then add +1 and another one -1  to the botton.
for the last one, keep the number intact in the selected location.

```
<a class="button_green" href="example.com/b/%num_up%/" rel="">continue to B%num_up%</a>
<a class="button_blue" href="example.com/%letter_up%/002/" rel="">move to %letter_up%2</a>
<a class="button_green" href="example.com/b/%num_down%/" rel="">go back to B%num_down%</a>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript, you could create a function that creates links for you. I have shared the approach below.

```js
function createLink(letter = "b", num, className, text) {
  const base = "example.com";
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = `${base}/${letter}/${num}/`;
  a.classList.add(className);
  a.innerText = text;
  return a;
}

const link1 = createLink("b", "003", "button_green", "Continue to B3");
const link2 = createLink("b", "002", "button_blue", "Move to A2");
const link3 = createLink("b", "001", "button_green", "Go back to B1");
```

And then use it in your HTML by doing something like this

```js
const root = document.querySelector('.root')

root.appendChild(link1)
root.appendChild(link2)
root.appendChild(link3)
```

Comment: I need that the JS will take "my location from the URL , and insert new link base on the % parameter in the template location
so when im in A it will change only the A to B, and the second button change only the 001 to 002 base on my location +1 to number  in the text and link and the second button switch from A to B, or B to A)

Comment: You should correctly mention what is exactly needed in the question